# Does JFrame.paintAll() work in Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe, paint

In our enterprise, we use JFrame.paintAll() to make a screenshot of our own (open-source) application. Unfortunately this does only work on Windows and Mac OS, but on Linux it does not work.

In a [German forum](http://www.java-forum.org/awt-swing-javafx-swt/79250-container-jframe-zeichnet-aufruf-paintall.html) I found a SSCCE:

```
public class SSCCEPaint
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       //create a simple JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //craate an image to draw
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(300,300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

        //paint the whole JFrame on the picture 
        frame.paintAll(g);

        //Show the picture in a second frame
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Picture");
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.add(new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img))));
        frame2.setSize(300,300);
        frame2.setLocation(200,0);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This SSCCE seems to work according to the guys from the forum, but the author wants to paint his frame with the border. Therefore he finally uses JFrame.printAll().
By the way, printAll() works on my machine, but I want the screen shot without the border.

I also already wrote a workaround with the Robot class, but it is not as elegant as the paintAll() method. So I would prefer a paintAll()-solution.
I also tried frame.getContentPane().paintAll(), this works at least, but then the menu bar is not drawn.

Does anybody know more about this topic?

Comment: Have you tried `printAll` instead?  If you don't want the frame border, try using `getRootPane().printAll(g)`...